# Why is my Node script not updating the files after the questions are answered?

Tags: node.js, node-commander, inquirerjs

I am writing a Node.js script that clones a GitHub repository and then prompts the user with questions. With those answers, it should go through the files and replace the respective placeholder values with the users answers. The code runs and asks the questions, but does not update the files with the answers.

```
 #!/usr/bin/env node
    
    // const { program } = require('commander');
    // const { execa } = require('execa');
    // const inquirer = require('inquirer');
    // const fs = require('fs');
    // const path = require('path');
    
    import { program } from 'commander';
    import { execa } from 'execa';
    import inquirer from 'inquirer';
    import fs from 'fs';
    import path from 'path';
    
    program
      .command('make-plugin <folder-name>')
      .description('Clone repo and change values')
      .action(async (folderName) => {
        const repoURL = 'https://github.com/wpdev95/plugin-boiler';
        const targetFolder = path.resolve(process.cwd(), folderName);
    
        // Clone the repository
        await execa('git', ['clone', repoURL, folderName]);
    
        const questions = [
      {
        type: 'input',
        name: 'Test Plugin',
        message: 'What is the Name of your plugin?',
      },
      {
        type: 'input',
        name: 'test-plugin',
        message: 'What is the slug of your plugin?',
      },
      {
        type: 'input',
        name: 'Plugin Author',
        message: 'What is the author\'s name?',
      },
    ];
    
        // Ask questions only once
        const answers = await inquirer.prompt(questions);
    
        // Obtain the list of files
        const files = fs.readdirSync(targetFolder).filter(file => {
          const filePath = path.join(targetFolder, file);
          return fs.statSync(filePath).isFile();
        });
        
        for (const file of files) {
          const filePath = path.join(targetFolder, file);
          let content = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf-8');
        
          // Replace placeholders in the content
          for (const key in answers) {
            const placeholder = `{{${key}}}`;
            const replacement = answers[key];
            content = content.replace(new RegExp(placeholder, 'g'), replacement);
          }
        
          // Update PHP file name
      if (file === 'plugin-boilerplate.php') {
        const newPhpFileName = `${answers['plugin_slug']}.php`;
        const newPhpFilePath = path.join(targetFolder, newPhpFileName);
        fs.renameSync(filePath, newPhpFilePath);
      }
    
      // Write back to the file
      fs.writeFileSync(filePath, content, 'utf-8');
    }

    console.log('Plugin boilerplate was made successfully! Happy coding! :D');
  });

program.parse(process.argv);
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the code with a debugger?

Comment: @Bergi I haven't. Any recommendations on which to use?

Comment: No - you don't have much choice anyway. For nodejs, you'll use one that supports the Chome DevTools Protocol - see https://nodejs.org/en/guides/debugging-getting-started. That's either standalone devtools, or the one built into your IDE (if you are using any). (In theory, there's also a [CLI debugger](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html) but I can't recommend that for a beginner)

Comment: @Bergi I got the following message from the debugger `Process exited with code 1`